# htaccess replace domain and add language

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I've tried a few way, but I need some help with the redirect rules :(

What I need is

Redirect **domainA.com/pagename.php** to **domainB.com/pagename.php?lang=EN**

And

Redirect **domainA.com/directory/pagename.php**  to  **domainB.com/directory/pagename.php?lang=EN**

I've tried something like this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domainB.com/$1?lang=EN [P]
```

And

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=EN [L]
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^pagename.php$ http://domainB.com/pagename.php?lang=EN [R=301]            
    RewriteRule ^directory/pagename.php$ http://domainB.com/directory/pagename.php?lang=EN[R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(directory)?/([^/]+)$ http://domainB.com/$2?lang=EN [R=301,L]
```